# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSClient", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AuthService.o

Tags: xcode6

I git clone this ios project form 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services. That project is an example of using azure mobile service on ios. But when I compile it under XCode6, I get the follwing error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/JOHN/Src/iOS-MobileServices-Authentication/source/client/AuthenticationDemo/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Users/JOHN/Src/iOS-MobileServices-Authentication/source/client/AuthenticationDemo/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices
>   (3 slices) Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSClient", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AuthService.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSUser", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AuthService.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, build settings, set your valid architectures to just be "Standard Architecture (armv7, armv7s)" and not "Standard architectures (including 64-bit)"
and also set build active architecture only to No  in all cases ie debug and release.

Currently the SDK is built with support for 5.1 which doesn't support a 64 bit build.